# How to get interactive console with variables and functions from editor in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse

I've been using python's IDE for a few months now and just switched to eclipse. in python's IDE when I run a module I coud test my functions and variables in the console which was very handy however I can't find a way to do that in eclipse. I managed to get a python console but when I type x = 1 
in the text editor then type x and click enter in the console it gives me an error saying the variable is undefined instead of returning 1 like IDLE's console did. is there a way to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you explored Eclipse/PyDev's debugging features? http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html

Comment: yes but I can't seem to connect the console to my code, it gives me the following error message when I try to use one of my variables defined in the text editor: [Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console.